# Methods of solving relative motion questions using algebra or calculus

Tags: kinematics

I am looking for algebraic methods (that may involve calculus) to solve problems of course needed for closest approach and shortest distance apart. I understand that geometric methods are often much simpler, however I have an examination that includes this topic in the near future and obviously do not have time to gain the geometric intuition required for these questions, which is why I would prefer algebra-only methods, even if they are significantly more complicated.

An example of the type of question that I am talking about is as follows:

> At noon ship A is 10 km West of a second ship B. Ship A is travelling due South at a constant speed of 15 $ km h^{-1}$. Ship B is moving at a constant speed of 12 $ km  h^{-1}$.
>
> Find (a) the course B should set in order to pass as close as possible to A
>
> (b) the shortest distance between the two ships in the subsequent motion.

Please note that I'm not after an answer for this specific question; I'm interested in a general method (for situations involving straight, constant velocities only).

Comment: *"I'm interested in a general method."* Calculus.

Comment: Or to be less snarky, do you mean to exclude geometric solution or really want to restrict yourself to purely algebaric tools? I doubt there is a general solution in the latter case, and you'll need to bring a certain amount of understanding to get a general strategy even with calculus.

Comment: @dmckee I don't see the distinction between excluding a geometric solution or restricting myself to only algebra?. If some geometry is unavoidable, then I have no choice but to use it, but I would prefer a method that is primarily algebraic, because my main difficulty with these questions is drawing a good diagram.

Comment: I read " algebra-only methods" as excluding calculus. If that is not what you meant, you might want to clarify because it is likely that at least some of the other physics teachers here will read it the same way (we talk about algebra-based and calculus-based courses in physics, you see).

Comment: Of course, it also occurs to me that you might mean all the problem to be considered to be of this "two straight, constant velocities" problem in which case a purely algebraic result is almost certainly possible. But I wouldn't have defined that as "general".

Comment: @dmckee I was not aware of that. I edited the question to clarify - calculus is permitted. Also yes, I did mean straight, constant velocities. Sorry for the ambiguity. I will edit the question again to clear that up.

Comment: The current (v2) title reads extremely weird to J. Random Physicist as well as K. Random Mathematician, as they assume calculus and algebra to be distinct and quite different things. And certainly they have the view "calculus $\not\subset$ algebra".

Comment: Side note: More or less all constant velocity questions on an Euclidian space can be solved solely by linear algebra (although using calculus methods will usually be easier). Even some optimization problems, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29 (there is even a section "Derivation without calculus").

Comment: @SebastianRiese I have edited the question once more, hopefully for the final time. I think it is quite clear now.

Answer (score 1):

1. Write an parameterized expression for both obejct positions as a function of time and any parameters to be optimized over, in the ground reference frame (putting the origin at any convenient place:
   $$\begin{align*}
   \vec{x}_a &= \vec{x}_a(t;a,b,c,\dots)\\
   \vec{x}_b &= \vec{x}_b(t;\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\dots)
   \end{align*}$$
2. Subtract $\vec{x_a}$ from both of these to get the parameterized expressions for position in a reference frame linked to object $A$ (using capital roman letters):
   $$\begin{align*}
   \vec{X}_a &= \vec{0}\\
   \vec{X}_b &= \vec{x}_b(t;\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\dots) - \vec{x}_a(t;a,b,c,\dots)\\
   &= \vec{X}_b(t;a,b,c,\dots;\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\dots)
   \end{align*}$$
   Notice that in this frame object $A$ occupies the origin for all time.
3. At any given time the distance of object $B$ from object $A$ is
   $$\begin{align*}
   R &= \sqrt{X_{b,x}^2 + X_{b,y}^2 + X_{b,z}^2} 
   \end{align*}$$
4. Minimize either $R$ or $R^2$ (which is often less work) over time and all free parameters. (In your restricted case where both objects are in uniform motion there is presumably a general answer to this.)
5. Drink beer, coffee or other suitable reward.

---

In the general case (not necessarily uniform velocities) step 1 can be demanding. The rest is just plug-n-chug stuff. Not that from a physics point of view the capitalized reference frame is only inertial if object $A$'s motion is unifrom.